# CSS: Element's height based on the image height next to it?

Tags: css

I have a list view on my page which works fine.

But I need to figure out how to change the size of the height texts holder (the black area) so it is exactly same height as the image next to it.

This is what I have so far:

```css
.vid-items{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  text-align:center;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.vid-items img {
  width:45%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.vid-itemsTitle {
  width:50%;
  background-color:#000;
  padding:5px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:14px;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;     
}
```

```html
<div class="vid-items">
  <img class="itemsImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/846659478120366082/K-kZVvT8.jpg" >
  <div class="vid-itemsTitle">some texts can go here as a title... this can be anything... 1,2,34...
  </div>
</div>
```

I know this can be achieved using jquery but I rather do this with CSS if possible?

Could someone please advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case, flexbox is your friend.

```css
.vid-items{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border:1px solid red;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

.vid-items img{
  max-width:45%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  flex-grow:0;
}

.vid-itemsTitle{
  width:50%;
  background-color:#000;
  padding:5px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:14px;
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  align-self:stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="vid-items">
<img class="itemsImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/846659478120366082/K-kZVvT8.jpg" >
<div class="vid-itemsTitle">some texts can go here as a title... this can be anything... 1,2,34...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-direction:row; is default

Answer (score 1):

You can make via `display: flex` **[link](https://jsfiddle.net/webdevkumar/1cmzr0dy/1/)**

```css
.vid-items{
   text-align:center;
   border:solid 1px #ccc;
   position:relative;
   margin-bottom:5px;
   padding:10px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   
   display: flex;
 
}

.vid-items img{

 width:45%;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 

}

.vid-itemsTitle{
 width:50%;
 background-color:#000;
 padding:5px;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vid-items">
<img class="itemsImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/846659478120366082/K-kZVvT8.jpg" >
<div class="vid-itemsTitle">some texts can go here as a title... this can be anything... 1,2,34...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use display flex.

```css
.vid-items{
 display:flex;
 width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 
}

.vid-items img{
 width:45%;
}

.vid-itemsTitle{
 width:50%;
 background-color:#000;
 padding:5px;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:14px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   
 
}
```

```html
<div class="vid-items">
<img class="itemsImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" >
<div class="vid-itemsTitle">some texts can go here as a title... this can be anything... 1,2,34...</div>
</div>
```

or you can use `display: table`

```css
.vid-items{
 display:table;
 width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 
}

.vid-items img{
 width:100%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.vid-itemsTitle{
 display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: top;
 width:50%;
 background-color:#000;
 padding:5px;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:14px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   
 
}
```

```html
<div class="vid-items">
<img class="itemsImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" >
<div class="vid-itemsTitle">some texts can go here as a title... this can be anything... 1,2,34...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: am I right to think that display flex is not supported in all the browsers?

Comment: flex support is 97%. you can see here https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox